# «Ветеран войны труженик тыла...» Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения, однородные-неоднородные-определения

*Ветеран войны труженик тыла Иванов Иван.*

Однородные или неоднородные определения? Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Труженики тыла - это тоже ветераны войны. **Ветеран войны** более широкое понятие, **труженик тыла** - более конкретное. Думаю, что лучше всего писать эти звания-статусы через тире или **труженик тыла** в скобках, где **труженик тыла** будет своеобразным уточнением:

******Ветеран войны (труженик тыла) Иванов Иван.*** Или: Ветеран войны - труженик тыла Иванов Иван.***

На сайте Госуслуг есть страница, где рассматривается порядок присвоения звания. Там используются как раз скобки  [Госуслуги](https://www.gosuslugi.ru/14344/1/info):

***Присвоение звания "Ветеран Великой Отечественной войны" (труженик тыла)***

Получается, что оформлять названия этих статусов как однородные члены нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Ветеран войны, труженик тыла Иванов Иван.***

И не надо ничего изобретать. Есть такое понятие, как сближение  ***определений и приложений***. В данном случае признаки сближены по почетности званий и считаются **однородными**, и совсем неважно, что по семантике они могут обозначать разные понятия.

Вот пример: *Александра Сергеевна является ветераном труда, ветераном Великой Отечественной войны, тружеником тыла*. ...

Здесь говорится о том, какой перед нами замечательный человек, удостоенный всех этих высоких званий.